# Width css property is not apply in items inside flex parent

Tags: css

I am new in CSS and I want the buttons to be wider, they look very narrow, how can I achieve this? They should look like the container has no display flex

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.container button {
  width: 500px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>Button #0</button>
  <button>Button #1</button>
  <button>Button #2</button>
  <button>Button #3</button>
  <button>Button #4</button>
  <button>Button #5</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You have a `max-width` on the container that's less than the `width` you have set on the buttons, so would be expected either way although not very responsive. What are you trying to make them look like?

Comment: I am trying to set a 500px width to the buttons but the changes are not showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use `flex-shrink: 0` in button CSS.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.container button {
  width: 500px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```